# Concrete CMS 9.2: How to force user log out programmatically

Tags: concrete5

I'm developing a Concrete CMS package. I add/remove users to/from a group. The group has some page access permissions, that is if a user belongs to the group, they can visit a Dashboard/MyPackage page. If I remove a user from the group, they must not view the page.

But what actually happens - I as admin remove another user from the group and force the user to be logged out programmatically. But instead of the other user being logged out, I myself get logged out while nothing happens to the other user who can still view the page unless I'm logged in in another browser and click on the logout link - only then the removed group permissions get cleared. What's wrong with that?

```
$u->exitGroup($group);
$u->refreshUserGroups();
$u->logout();
```

What can I do to for the user logout regardless?

In fact that's not a programming issue because I still have the same problem if do the same actions in the Dashboard menu, i.e. remove the group from a user while he's logged in in another browser and he still can visit the page.

Comment: Yeah, concreteCMS adds the groups to the session. Therefor a loggout will do the job. I guess you create the User with e.g. `$u = $app->make(User::class);` or `$u = new User();`. But with that you create a user instance of the active user, which is, why you get logged out and not the desired user. So you need the id of the desired user to get the user instance like following: `$ui = $app->make(UserInfoRepository::class)->getByID($id); $u = $ui->getUserObject();`, where `$id` is the id of the desired user.